# Text is not getting printed in Python Pillow

Tags: python, image-processing, python-imaging-library

You can see I've a function proccess text which takes a text from a json and stores in variable text_content, Every property was working fine Untill i added the text wrap feature. What it does is if the text exceeds the width and height of the image it needs to return the exceeding text in the next line. Earlier when I didnt include this feature i used to get the text printed in the image.But now the text is invisible and only way to track is that i've enabled the underline and the underline is getting printed

```
def process_text(element_data, draw, certificate, participant_name, event_name, email):
    text_content = element_data["content"]
    x, y = int(element_data["style"]["x"]), int(element_data["style"]["y"])
    original_y = y  # Store the original y-coordinate
    font_size = element_data["style"]["font_size"]
    font_color = element_data["style"]["font_color"]
    font_opacity = int(element_data["style"]["font_opacity"])
    box_width = element_data["style"]["width"]
    box_height = element_data["style"]["height"]
    underline = element_data["style"]["underline"]
    bold = element_data["style"]["bold"]
    italic = element_data["style"]["italic"]
    rotate_angle = element_data["style"].get("rotate", 0)
    flip_x, flip_y = element_data["style"].get("flip_X", False), element_data["style"].get("flip_Y", False)
    font_bg_color = element_data["style"].get("font_bg_color", "")

    if bold and not italic:
        font_file = "timesbold.ttf"
    elif not bold and italic:
        font_file = "timesitalic.ttf"
    elif bold and italic:
        font_file = "timesbolditalic.ttf"
    else:
        font_file = "times.ttf"

    font_url = f"{font_path}/{font_file}"
    response = requests.get(font_url)
    if response.status_code != 200:
        raise ImageProcessingError(f"Failed to download font file from {font_url}")

    font = ImageFont.truetype(BytesIO(response.content), font_size)

    text_content = text_content.replace("{{name}}", participant_name)
    text_content = text_content.replace("{{event_name}}", event_name)
    text_content = text_content.replace("{{email}}", email)

    lines = text_wrap(text_content, font, box_width, box_height)

    for line in lines:
        temp_image = Image.new("RGBA", (box_width, box_height), (255, 255, 255, 0))
        temp_draw = ImageDraw.Draw(temp_image, "RGBA")

        if font_bg_color != "":
            bg_color = ImageColor.getrgb(font_bg_color)
            temp_draw.rectangle([(0, 0), (box_width, box_height)], fill=bg_color)

        font_color_rgba = ImageColor.getrgb(font_color) + (255,)

        if font_opacity != 100:
            bg_color = ImageColor.getrgb(font_bg_color) if font_bg_color else (255, 255, 255)
            blended_color = (
                int((1 - font_opacity / 100) * bg_color[0] + font_opacity / 100 * font_color_rgba[0]),
                int((1 - font_opacity / 100) * bg_color[1] + font_opacity / 100 * font_color_rgba[1]),
                int((1 - font_opacity / 100) * bg_color[2] + font_opacity / 100 * font_color_rgba[2]),
            )
            font_color_rgba = blended_color + (255,)

        text_width, text_height = temp_draw.textsize(line, font=font)

        rotated_text = temp_image.rotate(-rotate_angle, expand=True, resample=Image.BICUBIC)

        if flip_x:
            rotated_text = rotated_text.transpose(Image.FLIP_LEFT_RIGHT)
        if flip_y:
            rotated_text = rotated_text.transpose(Image.FLIP_TOP_BOTTOM)

        if underline:
            lx, ly = x, y + text_height + 4
            draw.line([(lx, ly), (lx + text_width, ly)], fill=font_color_rgba, width=2)

        certificate.paste(rotated_text, (x, original_y), rotated_text)
        y += text_height 

def text_wrap(text, font, max_width, max_height):
    lines = []
    words = text.split()
    current_line = words[0]
    for word in words[1:]:
        test_line = current_line + " " + word
        width, height = font.getsize(test_line)
        if width <= max_width and height <= max_height:
            current_line = test_line
        else:
            lines.append(current_line)
            current_line = word
    lines.append(current_line)
    return lines
```

The Texts which are invisible need to be printed